# RabbitMQ - internal routing possible?

Tags: rabbitmq

I found a nice plugin for copying messages from one broker to another and even change from queue to exchange, as I understood.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html

Is it possible to add a filter to the shovel?

Or is there another re-routing plugin which helps me doing that?

My original idea was to add a attribute-based and envelope based filter on Rabbit-Level which is copying messages of my interest to another exchange.

The alternative is to implement the filter on consumers end, but that looks like a waste of performance, because the original queue deals with about 20000 msg / minute.

As always any help is apreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to use a topic, add a queue binding to the topic with a routing key and then using shovel on this queue?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: never mind, we decided to switch to 'topic' right from the beginning, so it is way easier to handle the messages. I thought that was not possible because of politics inside the company, but I was wrong. thanks anyway for your support